# How to solve flutter inappwebview stopped working?

Tags: flutter

I have created an app to display html file with `flutter_inappwebview` plugin but i got errors as below:
pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_inappwebview: ^2.1.0
```

here is  my main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I run the code the app unfortunately stop.

This is an error in Emulator.

[image]

This is an error in Android Studio 3.5.3

[image]

Any solutions thanks?

Comment: Any error it throws, it will be good if you post error log here

Comment: I already updated error image thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at issue in github [issue link](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/260), here is the solution:

**From**

```
dependencies:
  flutter_inappwebview: ^2.1.0+1
```

**To**

```
dependencies:
  flutter_inappwebview:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview.git
```

Then run `flutter clean` and then run the app. It should solve the problem.